# Adding points in vector layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, vector-layer

I downloaded the point vector layer as an example from https://code.google.com/archive/p/geospatialpython/downloads?page=2 and uploaded it to QGIS.

The code below should append a point to the existing points of the vector layer:

```py
vectorLyr = QgsVectorLayer('/qgis_data/nyc/NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO.shp', 'Museums', "ogr")
vpr = vectorLyr.dataProvider()
pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(-74.80,40.549))
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(pnt)
vpr.addFeatures([f])
vectorLyr.updateExtents()
```

But, in the end, no new points have been added. What is the problem?

Comment: You have one error an one omission (please see my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one error and one omission. Your relative path (if your home path is **/home/user_name/**; because I believe that you use Linux) should be:

```
'qgis_data/nyc/NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO.shp'
```

and you need to add this **QgsVectorLayer** to registry.

Next code should work perfectly:

```
vectorLyr = QgsVectorLayer('pyqgis_data/nyc/NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO.shp', 'Museums', "ogr")
n_features = vectorLyr.featureCount() #added line
vpr = vectorLyr.dataProvider()
# Original code for QGIS 2.x
# pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(-74.80,40.549))
# For QGIS 3.x 
pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(-74.80,40.549)) 
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(pnt)
f.setAttributes([n_features]) #added line
vpr.addFeatures([f])
vectorLyr.updateExtents()

# QGIS 2.x: 
# QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLyr) #added line
# For QQGIS 3.x 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLyr)
```

as you can see at next image:

[image]

Isolate point is added **QgsPoint**.

**Note:** If you have some problem with relative path use absolute path. On the other hand, if you want to include FID value of this feature you need two additional lines.